# building a list with Recursion with Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a recursive predicate that builds a list like it's suposed to, the problem is that eventually it starts 'debuilding it' and gives me an empty list, the `linha` predicate is ok, it gives a value to `Vel`, and `Or`.

```
actualizarveiculos(_,[],D).

actualizarveiculos(Tempo,[(X,Y)|RestoVeiculos],NovaVeiculos):-
    linha(Y,Or,Vel),
    faz_andar_veic(Or,(X,Y),C,mod(Tempo,Vel)),
    append(NovaVeiculos,[C],D),
    actualizarveiculos(Tempo,RestoVeiculos,D).

faz_andar_veic(90,(X,Y),(X+1,Y),0).

faz_andar_veic(270,(X,Y),(X-1,Y),0).

faz_andar_veic(_,(X,Y),(X,Y),C):-
  C=\=0.
```

[the trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxo5hF15vtsLTUY4bnlPWjN2ZlE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You haven't provided the linha predicate, which means we cannot test-run it. Also if you could type  predicate names in english that would be convenient since "builds a list like its supposed to" does not really say how you want the list to be built.

Comment: just give a value to Vel and Or, and you can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it as follows:

```
actualizarveiculos(_,[],D, D).

actualizarveiculos(Tempo,[(X,Y)|RestoVeiculos],Acc, Res):-
    Or is 2,
    Vel is 2,
    faz_andar_veic(Or,(X,Y),C,mod(Tempo,Vel)),
    append(Acc,[C],D),
    actualizarveiculos(Tempo,RestoVeiculos,D, Res).

faz_andar_veic(90,(X,Y),(X+1,Y),0).

faz_andar_veic(270,(X,Y),(X-1,Y),0).

faz_andar_veic(_,(X,Y),(X,Y),C):-
    C=\=0.
```

**Test run:**

```
[debug]  ?- actualizarveiculos(5, [(-5,3), (-4,4), (-4,5)], [], Res).
Res = [ (-5, 3), (-4, 4), (-4, 5)] .
```

In the trace you provided you query `actualizarveiculos(5, [(-5,3), (-4,4), (-4,5)], N).` Since N is unbound then `NovaVeiculos` becomes unbound and then you do:  `append(NovaVeiculos,[C],D),` which probably does not do what you think it does or atleast what you intended it to do. What it does is that it tries to append an unbound variable with a list and the result is unified with another unbound variable which obviously can give an infinite number of solutions, e.g.:

```
[debug]  ?- actualizarveiculos(5, [(-5,3), (-4,4), (-4,5)], N).
N = [] ;
N = [_G3430] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454, _G3460] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454, _G3460, _G3466] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454, _G3460, _G3466, _G3472] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454, _G3460, _G3466, _G3472, _G3478] ;
N = [_G3430, _G3436, _G3442, _G3448, _G3454, _G3460, _G3466, _G3472, _G3478|...] ;
```

Hope it helps, comment if you have questions. Since you didn't provide the `linha/3` predicate I just exchanged it with two unifications:

```
Or is 2,
Vel is 2,
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpfull!

Comment: how do i do that?